# How do I make a GitHub repository into an exe?

Tags: windows, git, github, packages, repository

I know this is going to sound so dumb because I am new into software developing. I have found this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/lamazingco/playme) which I plan to modify. Let's just say I fork this repository and modify it. How would I then be able to export it from there. By export it I meant turn all of those files into one windows executable file. Thanks.

Comment: Executable or zipped?

Comment: Please be familiar with JavaScript, NodeJS and Electron framework first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no universal solution. There are too many programming languages, frameworks and build systems.

Since this is a JavaScript project that comes with a `package.json`, let’s take look:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron src/index.js",
    "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
    "dist": "electron-builder -mwl"
  },
```

We’re in luck: The author has defined some sensible scripts for testing the application and packing it for distribution. It appears this project uses [electron-builder](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder).

If you run...

- `npm start`, you can test the application.
- `npm run pack`, you get a directory with the contents of the package without really packing it.
- `npm run dist`, redistributable packages are created.

When creating the package, you receive, ...

- a macOS `.dmg` file with an app.
- a macOS `.zip` file with an app.
- a Linux self-contained `.AppImage` file.
- a Windows installer (NSIS).

It may not be possible to build for all platforms on all platforms.

Comment: One question. Do I enter the npm commands in cmd?

Comment: Yes. But if you don’t know that, you should probably start a lot smaller. Get to know JavaScript and NodeJS first, then use some NPM modules and then maybe start hacking away at this project.

Comment: When I enter the following npm commands I am just getting a bunch of errors. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: You probably didn’t run `npm install` or `npm ci`. Like I said: If you have no experience, get familiar with the field first.

Comment: Thanks it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

To export a Github repository, click the "Clone or download" button,
then choose "Download ZIP".
You will find the sources in the downloaded Zip file.

To download the released `.exe` file, click the "releases" button.
In the [Releases webpage](https://github.com/lamazingco/playme/releases)
you will find the
[PlayMe.Setup.1.0.3.exe](https://github.com/lamazingco/playme/releases/download/v1.0.3/PlayMe.Setup.1.0.3.exe)
file that you can download.

Comment: Thanks. What I want to do is though make a modified version of the software and then turn all of those files into one windows executable file.